# How can I pass referece from an object in AppDelgate to ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, coremidi

I created an App using a storyboard in Xcode. the App contains an UITabBarController (TBC) and some UIViewControllers (VC), controlled from the TBC.

In the AppDelegate a create an object (lets call it "myMidi") which will listen to incoming MIDI-Messages (CoreMidi). So I implement the interfaces of this myMidi-Object in my VC.
I connected the views to the TBC using the "Relationship" option in the Interface Builder (IB).

All VCs, created in the IB are a instance of my own VC Class. As i mentioned bevore, in this Class I implement the interface of the the myMidi-Object I created in the AppDelegate.
So every VC-instance holds an address of an myMidi-Object and need now the one and only reference which was created in AppDelegate.

So I am wondering how can I access to the current VC or the TBC which is displayed currently to pass this reference to my VC Class?

Or how else can I solve this issue. I guess I should do this somewhere in AppDelegate or should I hold the reference in the TBC too and pass it to every new VC when the VC will be created !?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want your `MyMidi` class's current (only?) instance to be available to your VCs?

If you only ever have one Instance, consider making `MyMidi` a singleton class and give it a class method à la `+ (MyMidi *)sharedInstance;` which always returns (and lazily initializes) the same object. That way, you can access it from anywhere.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like) on how to implement a singleton in Cocoa/Cocoa Touch.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I give the singleton a try.

Comment: There is a difference between **needing only one** instance and **ensuring only one** instance can be created, generally the former is preferable e.g. don't use a singleton unless you need to ensure only one instance can be created...

Answer (score 0):

Use nsdefaults `setObjec:forKey:` to pass the object and get it where you want. Or make a property in appdelegate and access it through

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (TappAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.object = yourObject;
```